# Constraint solving with choco: Finding unique solutions for a variable

Tags: constraint-programming, choco, constraint-satisfaction

I'm using Choco to solve a CSP. In the beginning, I create an array of variables `v` like this:

```
IntVar[] v = new IntVar[5];
```

After adding several constraints, I'll search for solutions and find multiple of them. However, I want only unique solutions for e.g. `v[4]`. So all solutions should have a different value in the `v[4]` variable.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add a constraint which excludes previous values for `v[4]`?

Comment: Do you mean that I should add a constraint, after I have found the first solution, to exclude the previous values?

Comment: Yes. That is a common method to enumerate solutions.

Comment: That worked for me! I thought that all the constraints should be posted upfront - that was my mistake. Thank you for your help.